# How to run screen executing a command over ssh with tty

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gnu-screen

I tried many things today to have ssh start a screen session which executes a command. The goal is to run a command on a remote machine and to be able to see the output and to detach and reattach latter. I want to do it from within a script without any interaction except detaching the screen session to close. No satisfying solution so far.

```
ssh -t ${host} "\
    source ~/.bashrc; \
    echo \"done.\"; \
    cd \"$exedir\"; \
    if [ \$? -ne 0 ]; then \
        echo \"could not cd into directory\"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
    echo \"executing remotexe.sh ...\"; \
    screen -S "remotexe" -t "remotexe" -R "nice -n$prio ./remotexe.sh ${exeparams[@]}";"
```

Some of the problems I encounter are related to the strange ways to pass commands to screen/ssh/bash which interfere with arguments and options (I don't quite understand why they do not use `--` to interpret whatever follows as commands with arguments). The above version almost works. The remaining difficulty is that commands in remotexe.sh (in particular make) obviously miss exports and definitions from `.bashrc`. This is why I tried to include the `source ~/.bashrc`. I tried to add similar commands or explicit exports to remotexe.sh but it behaves as if it was executed by /bin/sh. If I do a conventional ssh login I can immediately run the remotexe.sh script without error. I also tried adding `shell -$SHELL` to my `.screenrc`.

Where is the mistake in this solution? How can I correct it?

Comment: There seem to be some problems with the escaping of `"` in the last line. Try quoting the entire snippet with `'` instead of `"` to save yourself some of these escaping headaches.

Comment: Then the variables in the string will not be evaluated, right? I could of course excape the `"` in the string.

Comment: Pardon me. Then do it the other way round: use `"` to surround the snippet and `'` for any string within it.

Comment: The command above is passing `-n$prio` as an argument to ssh.  Remove the `"` before `nice` and the one before the `;`

Comment: There's no need to escape newlines in double quoted strings an reasonable shells.  Also, you can do `cd $exedir || exit 1`  There's no need to print an error message: `cd` will print one for you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code at all, and will not vouch for the sanity of this, but you definitely have a quoting error.  Try:

```
ssh -t ${host} "
    source ~/.bashrc;
    echo done.;
    cd \"$exedir\" || exit 1;
    echo executing remotexe.sh ...;
    screen -S remotexe -t remotexe -R nice -n$prio ./remotexe.sh ${exeparams[@]};"
```

Comment: Note that the trailing semi-colons are unnecessary.

Comment: I see what you mean. However in both cases `screen` shows that `-n19` is interpreted as argument for `nice` (don't ask my why). The main problem described above is unfortunately unchanged by your corrections.

Comment: What do you want the `-n` to be an argument for? Exactly what is the command you are trying to run via screen?  (It looks like you want `-n19` to be an argument to nice, so I'm confused.)

Comment: `nice -n$prio ./remotexe.sh ${exeparams[@]}`

Comment: I.e. I do want it as argument for nice and it is taken as argument for nice.